# Symfony-form not treated, if checkboxes are unchecked (= request empty)

Tags: forms, symfony, checkbox, toggle, is-empty

I have a form that has only two checkboxes. When both are unchecked the `request` is empty and so the submitted form is not treated in the controller.

Any idea, how I can post something in the request for 'unchecked' checkboxes?

#### MyChoiceFormType

```
    [...]

    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options) {

        $builder
            ->add('voucher_buy', CheckboxType::class, [
                'label' => 'buy voucher',
                'data'  => false,               // un-checked as default
                'label_attr' => [
                    'class' => 'switch-custom'  // Bootstrap-toggle (=switch-button)
                ],
            ])
            ->add('voucher_use', CheckboxType::class, [
                'label' => 'use voucher',
                'data'  => false,               // un-checked as default
                'label_attr' => [
                    'class' => 'switch-custom'  // Bootstrap-toggle (=switch-button)
                ],
            ])
        ;
    }

    [...]
```

#### controller

```
    [...]

    // generate the FORM
    $form = $this->createForm(MyChoiceFormType::class);


    // handle the submitted FORM
    $form->handleRequest($request);

    if ( $form->isSubmitted() && $form->isValid() ) {
        dd($form->getData());   // <-- not getting here, when both checkboxes are unchecked

        // form shall be treated here and then
        // redirect to another page
    }

    [...]
```

Comment: if it doesn't go in isValid, then you probably have errors. can you tell what you got when you dump $form->getErrors() ?

Comment: Errors is empty. Remark: The request is also empty (dump($request->request);)

Comment: what about $form->isSubmitted() ? is it true ?

Comment: you should add either a submit button (which would send its value without further  consequences) or a hidden field (hiddentype) with some random field. csrf_protection would be sufficient too. however, please check, that the submit button is inside the `<form>`

Comment: Have you disabled csrf protection? If not, an hidden input should be added, making the request non-empty (and increasing the overall security)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Dirty Hack

I added a hidden-field, that solved the issue.

#### MyChoiceFormType

```
    [...]

    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options) {

        $builder
            ->add('voucher_buy', CheckboxType::class, [
                'label' => 'buy voucher',
                'data'  => false,               // un-checked as default
                'label_attr' => [
                    'class' => 'switch-custom'  // Bootstrap-toggle (=switch-button)
                ],
            ])
            ->add('voucher_use', CheckboxType::class, [
                'label' => 'use voucher',
                'data'  => false,               // un-checked as default
                'label_attr' => [
                    'class' => 'switch-custom'  // Bootstrap-toggle (=switch-button)
                ],
            ])
        ;

        // as the from post will be empty, if both checkboxes are unchecked
        // this dummy-field only ensures that at least something is in the
        // posted form
        $builder->add('dummy', HiddenType::class, [
            'data' => 'only_dummy_data',
        ]);
    }

    [...]
```

Answer (score 1):

I learned one thing today: a unchecked checkbox is not transmitted. I don't unterstand why, I had one I need transmitting the false value because I meant doing something on PRE_SUBMIT with it. Well, I have a choiceType instead of the checkbox, it is not so pretty to look at, but it works!

Answer (score 0):

Have the same issue, dont understand why there is no option value for unchecked checkboxtype like 'unchecked_value' => false.

I have to manually go over submitted fields, check if field has not been submitted then I know it is missing in form submit and that means it equal to false.

this is in my class

```
public function setUncheckedReplacementFields(array $data)
{
    foreach($this as $property => $value){
        if(str_contains('Replacement', $property) !== false){
            if(!in_array($property, $data)){
                $method = sprintf('set%s', ucfirst($property));
                if(method_exists(this, $method)){
                    $this->$method(false);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

before I am persisting form I run this

```
$object->setUncheckedReplacementFields($request->request->get($form->getName()));
```

so if field is not part of form I know it has been unchecked and I loop over object to find those checkboxes and setting them to false in my case unchecked.